# Which of these is the better style for function definition in f#?

Tags: f#, ml

```
let rec ints = function n -> Link (n+1, ints) 
let rec ints2 n = Link (n+1 ,ints)
```

Which of these is a better style and why?

Answer (score 2):

The second one, because it is shorter. The first one, being short-hand for a pattern `match`, doesn't buy you anything.

For a little more detail, the first one is equivalent to

```
let rec ints n = 
  match n with
  | n -> Link (n+1, ints)
```

which is unproductive because it is just binding the parameter `n` to a shadowing variable `n`.

Comment: Technically, the second one is short-hand for a pattern match with one match case. See: http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2011/01/patterns-are-everywhere.html

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen said, the first one is inefficient.

If you really do want, you can use the `fun` keyword:

```
let rec ints3 = fun n -> Link (n+1, ints)
```

ints2 and ints3 are almost-identical in the internal representation. I see no point in always using this syntax, since it is just longer than ints2 and has no advantages at all.

To clarify:

You should use the `fun` keyword in general, but in more appropriate scenarios.

Comment: Note, there are examples where `fun` does not work - `let t = function |_ -> 1` compiles but `let t = fun |_ -> 1` does not compile

Comment: ``fun`` is not identical to ``function``, but to let with parameters. Of course that there is use for ``function``, just not in his example.